# For loop issues while inserting values in HashMap java

Tags: java, excel, data-structures, hashmap, apache-poi

I have an excel file where data looks something like below:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I am using apache POI library to read excel. So, I have created a HashMap object using single key with multiple values by using:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> listN = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now I want to print values by using key in such a way:

```
user1 ---> [firstName, lastName, companyName, domainName, comName, emailLogin, passwordLogin, personalEmail]
user2 ---> [ccc, ccc, aaa, bbb, vvv, abc@abc.com, abc, N]
user3 ---> [sss, sss, aaa, fff, vvv, abc2@abc2.com, abc, N]
```

Please find my code below what I tried below so far:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            List<String> listN = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
                    //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0

                    for(int j=0; j<noOfRow; j++){
                        for(int i=0; i<noOfColumn; i++){
                            if (currentCell.getRowIndex() == j && currentCell.getColumnIndex() == i) {

                                listN.add(currentCell.getStringCellValue());


                            } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                                System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue()+ "--");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                hashMap.put("user", listN);
            }

            for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();

                System.out.println(key+" ---> "+value);
            }

            System.out.println();
```

I am getting getting stuck below in between the loop and printing values in single line below find my output:

```
user ---> [firstName, lastName, companyName, domainName, comName, emailLogin, passwordLogin, personalEmail, ccc, ccc, aaa, bbb, vvv, abc@abc.com, abc, N, sss, sss, aaa, fff, vvv, abc2@abc2.com, abc, N]
```

Here is my code where I am getting stuck:

```
    for(int j=0; j<noOfRow; j++){
                            for(int i=0; i<noOfColumn; i++){
                                if (currentCell.getRowIndex() == j && currentCell.getColumnIndex() == i) {

                                    listN.add(currentCell.getStringCellValue());


                                } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                                    System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue()+ "--");
                                }
                            }
                        }
hashMap.put("user", listN);
```

How can I achieve the output for the same?

***ANY KIND OF HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!***

Comment: You said you wanted keys to be `user1`, `user2`, and `user3`, so why are you adding all of the rows with key `user`? --- You do know that one of the main characteristics of a `Map` is that duplicate keys are not allowed, right? So if you add the same key 3 times, only the last add stays in the `Map`? --- I'm confused about why you are confused about the result.

Comment: Maybe `hashMap.put("user" + currentRow.getRowNum(), listN);` would work better.

Comment: You are adding cell values of all rows to one `ArrayList`. This should be a new `ArrayList` each row. And you are putting all the `ArrayList` into the `HashMap` with the same key named "user". From your expected result it should be another key "user1", "user2", ... each row. But mainly your looping over the cells is illogically.  You are using `Iterator` for rows and cells and then additional `for` loops also for rows and cells. Do either the one or the other. And btw.: where `noOfRow` and `noOfColumn` are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

- this code snippet prints the way you want, check if it can help

  ```
              public static void main(String[] args) {
                  Map<String, List<String>> keyValue = new HashMap<>();
                  String[] value1 ={"hello","world"};
                  String[] value2 ={"hey","stackovr"};
                  keyValue.put("key1", Arrays.asList(value1));
                  keyValue.put("key2", Arrays.asList(value2));
                  for (Entry<String, List<String>> set : keyValue.entrySet()) {
                      System.out.print(set.getKey()+" ---> "+set.getValue());
                      System.out.println();
                  }
              }
  ```
- use System.out.println() just after 'System.out.println(key+" ---> "+value)'
- O/P
  `key1 ---> [hello, world]
       key2 ---> [hey, stackoverflow]`